# How to measure performance metrics of an microservices application?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, performance-testing

I deployed a web application on kubernetes cluster. This application consists of multiple nodes, and each node has multiple pods. How can I do the performance measurement of whole application? I can see some metrics results on prometheus/ grafana but these results for each node/pod, not for whole application. I am just trying to understand the bigger picture. For example, I see that application data is stored in redis(pod), but is it enough to look into only that pod to measure latency?

Answer (score 1):

Every kubelet has `cAdvisor` ([link](https://github.com/google/cadvisor)) integrated into the binary. `cAdvisor` provides container users an understanding of the resource usage and performance characteristics of their running containers. Combine `cAdvisor` with an additional exporter like `JMX exporter` (for java, [link](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter)), `BlackBox exporter` for probe-ing urls (response time, monitor http codes, etc. [link](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter)). There are also frameworks, that provide metrics such as Java Springboot on path `/actuator/prometheus` and you can scrape these metrics. There are many different exporters ([link](https://github.com/prometheus?q=exporter&type=all&language=&sort=)), with each doing something else. When you gather all these metrics, you can have a bigger overview about the state of your application. Couple this with handmade Grafana dashboards and Alerting (`AlertManager` e.g.) and you can monitor almost everything about your application.

As per the prometheus/grafana stack, I guess what you are talking about is the `kube-prom-stack` with default dashboards already implemented into them.

Comment: I see. However, how can I get the latency of an application? Since these exporters doesn't help to get latency/response time of the app. I was thinking I need to use some Prometheus method such as Histogram, Summary. Is it possible?